# Leaving Wordpress Core Files untouched shared between multiple blog installation

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress, shared

For many reasons I can't use the [wordpress network solution.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). I will have to maintain multiple wordpress sites on the same server and I'd like to share the core between them.

What I'd like to achieve is:

- for each domain, the root folder should contain only the wp-config.php file and the wp-content folder
- The wordpress core should be shared between multiple installation.

So far I tried:

- to find a solution involving the usage of symlinks but the `__FILE__` constant is giving me headaches ( [more info](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-loadphp-bei-clean-svn-install-mit-symlinks) )
- to find a solution involving mountpoints on a loopback device but I ended up with many more troubles than solutions.

Is there any way, maybe some apache module ? that would help me to achieve this ? I'd like to leave the wordpress core untouched if possible ( but a couple of core changes are welcome ).

Another NTH Feature would be having some routing functionality like: Apache checks if the requested file exists in the DOMAIN document root and, if not, it looks to the SHARED wordpress codebase.

Comment: Should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you find a solution? I found a similar question asked later: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229594/can-we-use-one-wordpress-installation-for-multiple-databases-domains-and-conten
In case you want to go with multisite without the privacy issues that come by default, I added an answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303657/can-you-have-multi-site-wp-and-keep-users-separate/386282#386282

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside-out approach. It is untested, but I think you could possibly get away with this strategy:

1. Create a `wp-content-<hostname>` folder for each host. You are going to use it in a minute.
2. Create a `wp-config-<hostname>.php` for each site (I am assuming separate host names). It should contain the database connection information as well as custom defines shown next.
3. A quick look through the core code verifies the use of constants like `WP_CONTENT_DIR`. If you can successfully define that in your `wp-config-<hostname>.php` file, then you are likely golden....**except** for plugins which assume that the content directory is always named `wp-content`.
4. Modify the original `wp-config.php` to `require()` the correct `wp-config-<hostname>.php` by examining `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

With some luck, you will have multiple sites and databases running off the same WP core, but not in multisite mode.